# Conditional join, spark scala (between limits)

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes.

df1:

```
Team, Sport, CostTicket
Stars, Fotball, 10
Circles, Fotball, 20
Stars, Basket, 12
Stars, Baseball, 14
Circles, Baseball, 25
```

and

df2:

```
Team, Sport, CostRange, LowerLimit, UpperLimit
Stars, Football, 0<3, 0, 3
Stars, Football, 4<10, 4, 10
Stars, Football, 11<22, 11, 22
Stars, Football, 24<25, 24, 25
Circles, Football, 0<4, 0, 4
Circles, Football, 5<10, 5, 10
Circles, Football, 11<20, 11, 20
Circles, Football, 21<30, 21, 30
Stars, Basket, 0<2, 0, 2
Stars, Basket, 3<7, 3, 7
Stars, Basket, 8<19, 8, 19
Stars, Basket, 20<30, 20, 30
Circles, Basket, 0<1, 0, 1
Circles, Basket, 2<4, 2, 4
Circles, Basket, 5<15, 5, 15
Circles, Basket, 16<30, 16, 30
Stars, Baseball, 0<10, 0, 10
Stars, Baseball, 11<20, 11, 20
Stars, Baseball, 21<30, 21, 30
Circles, Baseball, 0<4, 0, 4
Circles, Baseball, 5<10, 5, 10
Circles, Baseball, 11<20, 11, 20
Circles, Baseball, 21<30, 21, 30
```

I want to add a fourth column to df1 with the CostRange from df2.

The final result should be:

```
Team, Sport, CostTicket, Range
Stars, Fotball, 10, 5<10
Circles, Fotball, 20, 11<22
Stars, Basket, 12, 8<19
Stars, Baseball, 14, 11<20
Circles, Baseball, 25, 21<30
```

I have come this far, but it does not work. Is there someone that can help me with this?

```
val df1 = df2.withColumn("Range", df2("CostRange"))
  .where(df1("CostTicket") > df2("LowerLimit"))
  .where(df1("CostTicket") < df2("UpperLimit"))
  .where(df1("Team") === df2("Team"))
  .where(df1("Sport") === df2("Sport"))
```

Comment: You need to use the `join` function. You can't use two dataframes directly in `withColumn` as in your current code. Join on the first two columns and then the the rest of the computations.

Comment: Could you explain the logic behing first two output?  `Stars, Fotball, 10, 5<10
Circles, Fotball, 20, 11<22`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't select two columns from two different dataframes, You need to join two dataframes first

You can join with two columns first and use `where` as below

```
df1.join(df2, Seq("Team", "Sport"))
    .where($"CostTicket"  >= $"LowerLimit" && $"CostTicket" <= $"UpperLimit")
```

Or you could specify in join condition itself as below

```
df1.join(df2,
    df1("Team") === df2("Team") &&
    df1("Sport") === df2("Sport") &&
    df1("CostTicket") >= df2("LowerLimit") &&
    df1("CostTicket") <= df2("UpperLimit")
).drop(df2("Team"))
 .drop(df2("Sport"))
```

Output:

```
+-------+--------+----------+---------+----------+----------+
|Team   |Sport   |CostTicket|CostRange|LowerLimit|UpperLimit|
+-------+--------+----------+---------+----------+----------+
|Stars  |Football|10        |4<10     |4         |10        |
|Circles|Football|20        |11<20    |11        |20        |
|Stars  |Basket  |12        |8<19     |8         |19        |
|Stars  |Baseball|14        |11<20    |11        |20        |
|Circles|Baseball|25        |21<30    |21        |30        |
+-------+--------+----------+---------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Works fine! Thanks.